# Statistical significance when comparing two models for classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, statistical-significance

I have been reading many deep learning papers. In some of them, I see the term **statistical significance** when they compare predicted results by models in a given dataset.

So, suppose you have two classifiers `A` and `B`. You use these models to classify a dataset with 1000 samples and get the accuracies `X` and `Y` for `A` and `B` respectively.

Could you give examples when one of the models is/isn't better/worse with statistical significance?

I know that this question has to do with null hypothesis, p-value and related topics. However, I can't figure out how to relate this to a dataset and models predicting labels from the dataset.

Answer (score 12):

Simply speaking, the performance metrics used are statistics derived from our test set. We can go ahead and compute confidence intervals around these statistics as we would do in a classical setting.

For example, let's say we use Accuracy (which is *not* good metric for classification), i.e. the proportion of correctly classified items in our test set. We can treat this statistics as coming from a binomial distribution and ask about its correspond [binomial proportion confidence intervals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval). Let's say that we have $N=100$ training points and classifier $C_1$ classified $80$ items correctly while classifier $C_2$ classified $83$ items correctly. The Wilson confidence interval for a type I error probability $\alpha =0.05$ would be 
$[0.711, 0.866]$ for classifier $C_1$ and $[0.744, 0.891]$ for $C_2$. Usual hypothesis testing would suggest that $C_1$ and $C_2$ do not have substantially different performance in terms of accuracy. What if we had $N = 10000$ and classifier $C_1$ classified $8000$ items correctly while classifier $C_2$ classified $8300$ items correctly? The confidence intervals would be $[0.792, 0.807]$ and $[0.822, 0.837]$ for classifiers $C_1$ and $C_2$ respectively. This would suggest that $C_1$ and $C_2$ have different performance on this test set.

Notice, that I simply used a parametric approximation to get the CIs for Accuracy. 
I would strongly suggest using bootstrapping to get a non-parametric estimate of the distribution of metric of interest. You can then use a paired sample hypothesis test.

I would suggest looking at some classic references like: "*[Approximate statistical tests for comparing supervised classification learning algorithms](https://sci2s.ugr.es/keel/pdf/algorithm/articulo/dietterich1998.pdf)*" by Dietterich or "*[Statistical comparisons of classifiers over multiple data sets](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume7/demsar06a/demsar06a.pdf)*" by Demšar for more details; they explicit look into paired $t$-tests and ANOVA approaches. I also found Derrac et al.'s "*[A practical tutorial on the use of nonparametric statistical tests as a methodology for comparing evolutionary and swarm intelligence algorithms](https://sci2s.ugr.es/sites/default/files/files/TematicWebSites/sicidm/2011-Derrac-SWEVO.pdf)*" quite nice to follow (and more generally applicable than its title would suggest).