# Performance comparison of two models on same dataset

Tags: cross-validation, model-selection, bootstrap, model-evaluation

In short, I'm curious as to the right approach for comparing model performances.

Some don't generate distributions or confidence intervals and compare point metrics. Some do generate distributions (i.e. repeated CV), but don't perform any tests that would yield a p-value. Few perform something like a t-test on bootstrapped metrics, however, the fact that increasing the number of bootstrap samples inflating significance seems intuitively wrong.

So my thought is to generate a list of metrics for both models from repeated CV (with fixed seed), then calculate the proportion of times model A performs model B and use that as an empirical p-value. So if A outperforms B >95%, then at a significance level of 0.05, we reject the null hypothesis that both models perform equally, and that A outperforms B.

Is this a ridiculous procedure, or is there a kernel of merit to this idea?

Please let me know, thanks!

Comment: Bootstrap 're-samples' should not be considered as additional information that increase information about the population. They are a computational device to assess variability in order to make a confidence interval. [By contrast, many traditional CIs use  an 'estimated standard error' to assess variability; no one would consider using data to estimate a SE as generating additional information about the population.]

Comment: Well I tend to agree, but then I see posts like [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/384466/statistical-significance-when-comparing-two-models-for-classification) where they recommend bootstrap + t-test

Comment: Whatever you may see online about bootstrapping, no competent source will lead you to believe that re-sampling provides new information about the population.

Comment: For future reference/other folks coming across this question, it seems like the critical work in this domain is: [Approximate Statistical Tests for Comparing Supervised Classification Learning Algorithms](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6790639) by Dietterich who recommends 5-repeat 2-fold CV with a (modified) paired t-test but admits that more repetitions will inflate significance which is echoed in Data Mining by Witten and Frank. Neither propose a "theoretically sound" method of comparison, which leads me to believe there is no "ideal" solution.